# How to make background not scroll but foreground scroll?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I am use Flutter for web for make website. I need make foreground scroll, but background not scroll like normal website. For example: [codemagic.io](https://codemagic.io) .
I cannot use Scaffold background because I want use use `CustomPainter` for custom background.

I am try use `Stack`, but issue is I need `Center` Widgets in `ScrollView`, and if I do this then the CustomPainter is not start from top of page:

```
Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Center(
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child:
Stack(children: <Widget>[

  CustomPaintWidget(),



                  Widgets(),


],),
```

Anyone know solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have two stacks here and one is only holding one widget (basically pointless for what you want to do). Put a widget on the bottom index of that stack (0) and make it the size of its container. You could use LayoutBuilder to get the size of its parent widget. Then place the singlechildscrollview on top of that.

Comment: Thanks for reply! But this is not work. I try you solution but widget is not center in `SingleChildScrollView`. You can post code?

Comment: So then wrap the widget that's inside of the SingleChildScrollview in a Center widget.

Comment: I have try this. Wrap in `Center` widget not change this. Still display at top not center